# "General error during conversion: Unsupported class file major version 61" in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Recently I have updated my Java from 1.8 to 17 and started noticing this error, how to fix this ?

Error Details:

```
2023-03-13 12:48:59,523 ERROR o.a.j.a.JSR223Assertion: Problem in JSR223 script: Status-Code-Checker
javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
General error during conversion: Unsupported class file major version 61

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61
at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:196)
at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:177)
at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:163)
at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:284)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmDecompiler.parseClass(AsmDecompiler.java:81)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.findDecompiled(ClassNodeResolver.java:251)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.tryAsLoaderClassOrScript(ClassNodeResolver.java:189)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.findClassNode(ClassNodeResolver.java:169)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.resolveName(ClassNodeResolver.java:125)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmReferenceResolver.resolveClassNullable(AsmReferenceResolver.java:57)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmReferenceResolver.resolveClass(AsmReferenceResolver.java:44)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.ClassSignatureParser.configureClass(ClassSignatureParser.java:42)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.DecompiledClassNode.lazyInitSupers(DecompiledClassNode.java:185)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.DecompiledClassNode.getGenericsTypes(DecompiledClassNode.java:80)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.GenericsVisitor.checkGenericsUsage(GenericsVisitor.java:131)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.GenericsVisitor.checkGenericsUsage(GenericsVisitor.java:125)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.GenericsVisitor.visitDeclarationExpression(GenericsVisitor.java:104)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.DeclarationExpression.visit(DeclarationExpression.java:89)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.CodeVisitorSupport.visitExpressionStatement(CodeVisitorSupport.java:117)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitExpressionStatement(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:200)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement.visit(ExpressionStatement.java:40)
```

Observing this from my JSR223 Assertion,

```
import org.apache.jmeter.assertions.AssertionResult;

def failureMessage = "";
def resCode = SampleResult.getResponseCode();

if (!resCode.equals("200")) {
  failureMessage = "Got Response Code :" + resCode;
  AssertionResult result = new AssertionResult("Expected Response 200");
  result.setFailure(true);
  result.setFailureMessage(failureMessage);
  prev.addAssertionResult(result);
  prev.setSuccessful(false);
  SampleResult.setStartNextThreadLoop(true);
} else {

}
```

My Java version:

```
java version "17.0.6" 2023-01-17 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+9-LTS-190)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.6+9-LTS-190, mixed mode, sharing)
```

It was working previously and recently I have upgraded my Java and noticing this error.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you "have upgraded my Java" you should think about upgrading JMeter as well as it looks like you're sitting on the version which is being shipped with [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) which doesn't support Java 17.

For example latest stable [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5) comes with [Groovy 3.0.11](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.5/gradle.properties#L92) which works fine with Java 17

[image]

Moreover it's strongly [recommedned to use latest JMeter version where/if possible](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version)